# about databases in android

Tags: android

i am new in android database.i downloaded sqlite database browser.
can u give me the steps how to use already generated database in android sdk with eclips.
give me proper structure where to store database in eclips folder structure

Comment: What have you done so far and what exactly can you not get to work

Answer (score 2):

When you create a database in your application, it is stored in

> /data/data/com.zenika.droidcontact/databases/nameOfYourDatabase.db

You can find this file by going in the DDMS perspective in Eclipse, in the file explorer view, select the emulator and then, follow the path here above to your file. Then, select it and you can use the "Pull a file from device" to get this database on to your computer. Then you can start SQLite Database Browser. now you can open your file, modifiy it in the software, execute request with the 3rd tab, browse tables and data with the first and second. Then, you can save the database modified and push it back onto the emulator just the same way as you pulled it, but with the push button.
Is this clear or do you need more explanation?